# If the Liouville Constant is transcendental, is its exponentiation also transcendental?

Tags: transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

So we have Liouville's Constant:

$L_b=\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}b^{-n!}=\left(0.\textbf{1}\textbf{1}000\textbf{1}00000000000000000\textbf{1}00000000...\right)_b$

And let $M$ be the constant defined as: (is there a name for this constant?)

$M_b=\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}b^{-\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n}{2}-1}=\frac{\theta_2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\right)}{2b^{7/8}}=\left(0.\textbf{1}\textbf{1}0\textbf{1}00\textbf{1}000\textbf{1}0000\textbf{1}00000\textbf{1}000000\textbf{1}...\right)_b$

My question is, are either of $e^{L_b}$ or $e^{M_b}$ transcendental? How would one go about proving or disproving that $e^{L_b}$ or $e^{M_b}$ are transcendental?

Or, if $L$ is any Liouville Number (therefore $L$ is transcendental), is $e^L$ transcendental?

How about $10^L$?

Comment: I think this might be open. We do not know the rationality of $e^e$ for example.

Comment: I even highly doubt that it is known whether those numbers are irrational. Even irrationality proofs are usually extremely difficult, for example $\ e+\pi\ $ or $\ e\cdot \pi\ $ are not known to be irrational.